# JOIN to include fields in the secondary table override WHERE

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT  d.account_id,
            d.product,
            d.month,
            sum(d.spend),
            u.lifetime_product_spend
    FROM FLATTEN(data_source, product) d
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT  account_id,
               product,
               SUM(product_spend)/1000000 lifetime_product_spend
               FROM usage
               GROUP BY account_id, product) u
    ON (d.account_id = u.account_id AND d.product = u.product)
    WHERE d.month >= DATE_ADD(today ,-5,"MONTH")
    GROUP BY d.account_id, d.product, d.month, u.lifetime_product_spend
```

Due to the sheer amount of data, I'm only able to include the last 6 months data. That's why I'm calculating the lifetime spend in a different table and joining them. The output looks like this:

```
table: monthly                        
account_id         product           month         spend      lifetime_product_spend       
=====================================================================================
    A              product1           1             10                   50
    A              product1           2             20                   50
    A              product1           3             30                   50
    A              product2           1             5                    20
    A              product2           2             15                   20
    B              product2           2             100                  100
    B              product3           2             100                  150
    B              product3           3             50                   150
    C              product3           1             100                  500
    C              product3           2             400                  500
```

The problem is, for products with spend prior to the 6 months, those product line items do not get included because of the WHERE DATE_ADD filter. I tried a RIGHT JOIN to the subquery, but I think the WHERE parameter overrides that. I'd like to include the product line-items that show up in the subquery even if they occur prior to the 6 months window. For the month and spend columns, they'd be NULL, but I'd still have the lifetime_product_spend and account_id.

Thanks for the help. Please let me know in the comments if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Something like below
I removed WHERE clause and modified rows for d.month and sum(d.spend)
Haven't tested, but should be close to working version

```
SELECT  
  d.account_id,
  d.product,
  CASE WHEN d.month >= DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE() ,-5,"MONTH") 
       THEN d.month ELSE NULL 
  END AS d_month,
  SUM(CASE WHEN d.month >= DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE() ,-5,"MONTH") 
           THEN d.spend ELSE 0 
      END) AS d_spend,
  u.lifetime_product_spend
FROM FLATTEN(data_source, product) d
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT  
    account_id,
    product,
    SUM(product_spend)/1000000 lifetime_product_spend
  FROM usage
  GROUP BY account_id, product
) u 
ON (d.account_id = u.account_id AND d.product = u.product)
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not fully clear on what the desired result is but I believe you want to get the entries for the last 6 months plus the total spend from the SUM function.

Your WHERE clause is what is limiting your query to 6 months but I think you know this. The problem is it is limiting the scope of the query rather than filtering the result, so you will not be able to get a SUM with a WHERE clause in this way. In other words your WHERE will supersede your SUM.

You could JOIN what you have there(minus the spend calculation) with a separate query to get the account id and the spend from the full table and it should give you your desired output.